# Attempting to close antivirus software after scan is finished

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to close Malwarebytes and other antivirus programs when a scan is finished, currently I'm using the CPU usage as a sign the scan is finished but there are multiple processes run by Malwarebytes and my program only picks up the one running at 0% CPU usage most of the time
This is my code

```
    public static PerformanceCounter process_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process","% Processor Time", "mbam");
    public static Process proc = new Process();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double CPU_use = process_cpu.NextValue();
        temp = temp + CPU_use;
        Count += 1;
        TBX1.Text = Count + ": Seconds Opened";

        if (proc.Responding)
        {
            TBX1.Text += "  Status = Running  CPU usage is " + CPU_use;

            if (temp <=  0 && Count % 20 == 0) //this checks every 20 secs
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Finished?", "END"); //This is temporary, it will just end the program 
            }
            if (Count % 20 == 0)
            {
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TBX1.Text += "  Status = Not Responding";
        }  
    }
```

}

Is there a better way of doing this? or am I going to have to select the process running?

Comment: It seems that if you can get the PID of MBAM, you could examine all the processes to find if they are children of it: [How to find the child processes associated with a PID?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d60f0793-cc92-48fb-b867-dd113dabcd5c/how-to-find-the-child-processes-associated-with-a-pid). Would that be of any use to you?

Comment: Malwarebytes pops up a Notepad window once a test is completed. You can have your program check periodically for that window and close Malwarebytes once it pops up. Just a workaround and probably good enough only if this is for personal use.

Comment: You shouldn't have to keep a count to check for 20 seconds.  The timer object you created should have an Interval property that you can set to 20000, because that property is set in milliseconds.

Comment: Andrew, I'm not entirely sure how that's worded I need to get the PID of one process and follow the CPU usage of that. Unfortunately it's not just malwarebytes, it's also oter programs but thank you TH Todorov. I'm counting something every second so it's the easiest way to do it shar1er80. Thank you for the response